# How to make a Curl POST call in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, curl

I am trying to issue the following command under Windows 10:

```
D:\>curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{  "firstName" : "Frodo",  "lastName" : "Baggins" }' http://localhost:8080/people
```

Unfortunately, it produces numerous errors:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: firstName
curl: (7) Failed to connect to  port 80: Connection refused
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Frodo,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: lastName
curl: (7) Failed to connect to  port 80: Connection refused
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Baggins
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 1
```

Apparently, it does not understand the syntax.

Why is this, and how can this be fixed?

```
D:\>curl --version
curl 7.46.0 (x86_64-pc-win32) libcurl/7.46.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2e zlib/1.2.8 WinIDN libssh2/1.6.0
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile SSPI Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM SSL libz
```

Comment: You can always try using git bash on windows to feel more unix comfortable on windows

Answer (score 25):

Another option is to mask doublequotes with backslash like this:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{\"firstName\": \"Frodo\",  \"lastName\" : \"Baggins\" }" http://localhost:8080/people
```

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you're using `cmd.exe`. Command Prompt's character escaping rules are both archaic and awful. I recommend using Powershell instead; it uses rules much more similar to those of `bash` on other *nix shells (though not identical, notably because it uses ` (backtick) as the escape character instead of backslash).

Here's the command in Powershell on my system:

```
& 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\curl' -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{  "firstName" : "Frodo",  "lastName" : "Baggins" }' http://localhost:8080/people
```

The leading `&` is required because the path to the program is a quoted string. I had to specify the path because I don't have a `curl.exe` in my Windows `PATH`. However, I could just escape the space in "Program Files":

```
C:\Program` Files\Git\mingw64\bin\curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{  "firstName" : "Frodo",  "lastName" : "Baggins" }' http://localhost:8080/people
```

Single and double quotes otherwise work as you're using them, with the `'` delimiting the start of a string and the `"` appearing just as literal characters inside it.

Note that you *do* have to provide the path to a `curl` executable, or at least specify `curl.exe`; `curl` by itself is a Powershell alias for the `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet, which can do most of what the cURL program can do but has very different argument syntax.

Also, while you *can* invoke Powershell from `cmd` using `powershell -c <command>`, that wouldn't really help here because you'd have to escape the string using `cmd`'s silly syntax anyhow.

---

Another option is just to use the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), which lets you run Linux programs (including the default Ubuntu versions of `bash` and `curl`) directly on Windows, no VM or rebooting needed. Full details about this can be found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about, but the short version is try running `bash` (or `bash.exe`) from any Command Prompt or Powershell window, and it will install the Linux subsystem or at least tell you how.

Comment: For newcomers to the thread, Curl been included in Windows 10 for a while now.

source: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Containers/Tar-and-Curl-Come-to-Windows/ba-p/382409

To check if your Windows 10 has it, run the following from PowerShell or CMD: `C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe --help`

Comment: I get this: {"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Unexpected token u in JSON at position 2"}

This is my command:
curl.exe -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "username": "Code", "password": "Witcher" }' http://localhost:3000/login

What's the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your -d argument with double quotes as the argument. You need to surround it in quotes and escape the double quotes inside.

You should be able to do:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{  ^"firstName^" : ^"Frodo^",  ^"lastName^" : ^"Baggins^" }" http://localhost:8080/people
```

Personally, I'd stick them in a file, then use -d @filename for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Windows curl doesn't aware of single quotes. Therefore, you can use double quotes for your payload and escape any other double quotes inside that payload. That comes out like below:

```
curl -d "{\"firstName\": \"Frodo\",  \"lastName\" : \"Baggins\" }" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST http://localhost:8080/people
```

Comment: You're confusing an operating system (Windows) with a shell (Command Prompt a.k.a. CMD). Powershell, and Unix shells such as bash, support multiple quote types just fine even when run on Windows.

Answer (score -1):

Another workaround in Windows is to use bash from Cygwin.  I had the same problem, with bash it works for me.

For Windows 10, the built-in Linux application support might handle the single quotes as well.

Comment: Why in the world would you use Cygwin when Win10 has fully Linux application support? May as well use Wine on Windows!

Comment: @CBHacking, the question is not tagged Windows 10, is it?

Comment: @Arjan It should be (and now is) as the OP said in the question "I am trying to issue the following command under Windows 10"

Comment: In that case, and _if_ the built-in Windows 10 Linux support also supports the single quotes like Cygwin, then I'd prefer an edit for the answer, @David.